# Adjuntar al proceso en Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Alguien sabe como adjuntar Visual Studio Code a otro proceso?

Necesito hacer debug de un addin de excel pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.
En Visual Studio si puede hacerse pero el IntelliSense funciona peor cuando se trata de trabajar con un conjunto de ficheros python que no están dentro de ningún proyecto.

Un saludo

Comment: Vale gracias, he añadido mas información. Aunque según veo los saltos de linea no los interpreta como tal. Lo revisare

Comment: si tenes dudas sobre como funciona el sitio o alguna otra, revisa el [tour] y tambien [ask]